# find birthday,wedding anniversary details from employee and show in kanban view

Tags: odoo-12

I want to inherit "hr.employee" and "kw_greetings_category" to my model "kw_send_wish". And after inheriting i want to show these employee name, birthday(today's birthday), wedding anniversary(today's) and employee code which are from "hr.employee" and greetings_category_id from "kw_greetings_category" model details in kanban view.

I have created "kw_send_wish" model and inherit those models but I can't show the field in kanban view.

### kw_send_wishes.py

```
from odoo import models, fields, api

class kw_send_wish(models.Model):
    _name = 'kw_send_wish'
    _inherit = ['hr.employee','kw_greetings_category']
```

### kw_send_wishes_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record id="kw_send_wish_view_kanban" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Send Wish</field>
        <field name="model">kw_send_wish</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <kanban default_group_by="birthday">
                <field name="id"/>
                <field name="birthday"/>
                <field name="gender"/>
                <field name="personal_email"/>
                <field name="cname"/>
                <templates style = "background-color:#f4f6f6 ">
                    <t t-name="kanban-box" >
                        <div t-attf-class="oe_kanban_global_click ">
                            <div class="o_kanban_image">
                                <img t-att-src = "kanban_image('kw_send_wish','image',record.id.value)" align = "right" height="80px" width="80px" />                            </div>
                            <div class= "o_dropdown_kanban dropdown">

                            </div>
                            <div class="oe_kanban_body">

                                <div class="oe_kanban_details" style="padding-left:80px ;">
                                    <field name="birthday"/>
                                    <field name="gender"/>
                                    <field name="personal_email"/>
                                    <field name="cname"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class = "oe_kanban_footer">
                                <div class= "oe_kanban_footer_left">
                                </div>

                                <div class= "oe_kanban_footer_left">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class = "oe_clear" />
                        </div>
                    </t>
                </templates>
            </kanban>
        </field>
    </record>


    <record id="kw_send_wish_action_window" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Send Wishes</field>
        <field name="res_model">kw_send_wish</field>
        <field name="view_mode">kanban,form</field>
        <field name="help" type="html">
            <p class="o_view_nocontent_smiling_face">
            No Details....
            </p>
        </field>
    </record>
</data>
```

after this code running it is not showing any kanban view, only empty view is showing no details is coming from models